# Issue with read_html when looping and reading from a dataframe

Tags: r, rvest

I have a data frame containing 100 rows of URL I would like to scrape data from. If I were to copy the URL in one of the row and save it inside a variable 'url' then do:

```
 webpage <- read_html(url, encoding = "windows-874").
```

Everything works fine, but if I were to do a loop that calls the data frame and do `read_html` row by row I get an error:

> "Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')""

I believe this has to do with the fact that `read_html` cannot read `tibble`s but I have not been able to figure out a solution around it. I tried changing the datatype of the URL inputting into `read_html` into all kinds of data types from character, numeric, vector etc, but none of them solve the problem. 
Your help would be much appreciated.

The data frame 'URLSetTrade' is an import from a csv file contains rows of data in this format:

```
row1 -> 'https://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp?txtSymbol=wha&ssoPageId=9&selectPage=10'
row2 -> 'https://www.settrade.com/AnalystConsensus/C04_10_stock_saa_p1.jsp?txtSymbol=prm&ssoPageId=9&selectPage=10'
etc. etc.
```

Function to read the url

```
getBatchAnalystData <- function(URLRow){
  url <- URLSetTrade[URLRow,1]
  webpage <- read_html(url, encoding = "windows-874") 
  target_price_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'td')
  target_price_data <- html_text(target_price_html)
  sub("-","",target_price_data)
```

OMITTED for simplicity
    analystPriceDataFrame <- data.frame(Number = double(), ............ and other codes to input the text obtained from reading the webpage into dataframe

```
return(analystPriceDataFrame)
}
```

The loop calling read url function

```
 for (i in 1:nrow(URLSetTrade)) {  assign(paste0(EarningDate2019_07_28_Cleaned[i,1],
  "AnalystData"),getBatchAnalystData(i))
    }
```

Comment: Are your row1 and row2 containing the same url? Should they be distinct urls?

Comment: That's very slight differences between the two rows. In row 1-> txtSymbol=wha and in row 2 -> txtSymbol=prm

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, `xml2::read_html` requires its input `x` to be a single url, rather than a vector (of length 2 or more) of urls. One way to use a single function call to read multiple urls is to use a function like `purrr::map`. `purrr::map` takes as inputs both a list and a function (`xml2::read_html` in our case) and returns the result of applying the function to every element of the inputted list. You might need to install `purrr` from CRAN if you haven't used it before.

```
mylist <- list("http://nytimes.com", "http://economist.com")
purrr::map(mylist, xml2::read_html)
```

From your question, it looks like you need to specify additional arguments to `read_html`. You can do this by naming them (with their values) in the call to `purrr::map`.

```
purrr::map(mylist, xml2::read_html, encoding = "windows-874")
```

where `mylist` is now a list of the urls that you really want (and not the urls that I pasted above). I hope that this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Fred. Your solution works perfectly!! However, now that read_html is working, the error then propagates to the next line instead. "html_nodes(webpage,'td')" returns an error 
"Error in UseMethod("xml_find_all") : no applicable method for 'xml_find_all' applied to an object of class "list""
I find this very strange because if I were to run the code without the loop using 
webpage <- read_html(url, encoding = "windows-874")
target_price_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'td')
the webpage variable is of type list. And there is no problem. Would you have any idea as to why?

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. The output of purrr::map() is a list, so you need to handle it as such. Before going further, can you successfully run `html_nodes(mylist[[1]], "td")`. If yes, then you should be able to replace your line that uses `html_nodes` with a call to purrr::map(), something like `purrr::map(htmls, html_nodes)`. What is the name of the argument that is set to 'td' in your code? You need to add this argument, with its name, to the call to purrr::map`.

Comment: Oh I should have said that `htmls` in my code above, is the output of `purrr::map(mylist, xml2::read_html)`

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much again for your help.